# get the label name from wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, function

i'd like to get the value of the label'name from a list item, and place it into the attribute data-menuanchor="".

like this:

```
 <li><a href="#home"> get this ==>Home<== get this </a></li>

       ==>   Place it here      <==
<li><a ==>data-menuanchor="Home"<== href="#Home">Home</a></li>
```

and do it for each list item:

```
<li><a data-menuanchor="Home" href="#Home">Home</a></li>
<li><a data-menuanchor="Contacts" href="#Contacts">Contacts</a></li>
<li><a data-menuanchor="AboutUs" href="#AboutUs">AboutUs</a></li>
```

i already have a function that i worte temporally but i have to manually add each section, like so:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'my_nav_menu_attribs', 10, 4 );

function my_nav_menu_attribs( $atts, $item, $args )
{
 // The ID of the target menu item
 $Home = 18; //menu ul li ==> id target
 $Contacts = 17; 


// inspect $item

if ($item->ID == $Home) {
$atts['data-menuanchor'] = 'Home';
}

elseif ($item->ID == $Contacts) {
$atts['data-menuanchor'] = 'Contacts';
}
return $atts;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) to set the attribute value, and use a function as the second param so that it will be called for each anchor

But you will need to target only the anchor's inside the menu, so assuming you have a class assigned to the `ul`(in the below code assuming `mymenuclass` is the class assigned to the ul)

```
$('.mymenuclass a').attr('data-menuanchor', function () {
    return $.trim($(this).text());
})
```

Comment: the ul class is .menu, gonna try this :)